# $.post in a each loop ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery

Have some simple jquery that Im trying to execute on a button click. For some reason it is not working. It "posts" the first element with class of 'editable' but not any others. I have about 9 elements in DOM that is should be looping through.

I taken a look with firebug at each post request and like I said the first is ok, but then the rest come back and '500 Internal Server Error'.

Below is my code, any ideas here?

```
$(".editable").each(function() {
            if (this.id != '') {
                //save content of each item
                $.post("/DynamicContent/SaveContent", { hid: this.id, content: $(this).html() }, function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                });

            }
        });
```

Comment: Upon further investigation, I removed the .html() from the content property, and everything seems to be posting to the controller fine now. the html() must be causing some sort of issue here.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably getting a HttpRequestValidationException from posting unencoded html. See [How to avoid HttpRequestValidationException in ASP.NET MVC rendering the same view which caused the exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249066/how-to-avoid-httprequestvalidationexception-in-asp-net-mvc-rendering-the-same-vie)

Comment: Mauricio, thanks! This seems to be my issue, should i encode the HTML?
Probably a safer bet right?

Comment: accepting html is not trivial, see http://www.google.com/search?q=xss+asp.net+mvc