# security problem when receiving a content from a texteArea in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, textarea

I am currently developing an application in asp mvc and I develop the UIL interface. I have an wysiwyg  but the problem when I validate, I have a security error due to my texArea contain Html code.

```
<%=Html.textArea("contenuHelp") %>
```

> Exception: System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: Une valeur Request.Form potentially dangerous has been detected from the client (contenuHelp="< font >color")

How i can fix it please ?

Thank :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249066/how-to-avoid-httprequestvalidationexception-in-asp-net-mvc-rendering-the-same-vie

Answer (score 0):

MVC's view restrict certain text that can be entered in the field for security reason and to prevent injection type hack.

If you must use style like **color** for the text area, you can apply it like this:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("contenuHelp", "", new { style = "font-color: red" })%>
```

The first parameter is the name of the field, second parameter is the value and third one is the html attributes you want to apply to the field.

Here is the MSDN complete documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.textareaextensions.aspx