# Passing a string formulation of XML to a web service on IIS

Tags: xml, vb.net, iis

I developed a web service in VB.NET with a web method that accepts a string as a parameter which must be in the form of an XML document.

I am able to open the browser and call the service up fine and it presents the text-box where I need to pass the string.

As soon as I pass any XML string by copying my XML and pasting it into the box then clicking invoke I get an error. I get this even when I put a string in the simplest XML form e.g just one node.

This is the error:

> System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Xmlin="<?xml version="1.0" ...").
>      at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
>      at System.Web.HttpValueCollection.EnsureKeyValidated(String key)
>      at System.Web.HttpValueCollection.Get(String name)
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
>      at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

Comment: Its actually a protection against malicious inputs. You need to disable the validation on the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following attribute above the method:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

This should allow it to read the XML rather than it throwing an exception because it could possibly be dangerous.

Warning: This will deactivate all validation for this, and could potentially leave your endpoint open to some forms of attacks or vulnerabilities. If you have any problems with any of this please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249066/how-to-avoid-httprequestvalidationexception-in-asp-net-mvc-rendering-the-same-vi) post asking a similar question.

Comment: Thank you ProNinja, let me try it out.

Comment: Hi there, tried adding <ValidateInput(False)> above the web method but does not seem to be recognised in vb.net. what class is it derived from? I know for webMethod I am using System.Web.Services

Comment: I think it's under `System.Web.Mvc`

Comment: Thanks @ProNinjacat. Your initial advice led me to do the correct thing. I The option is available in MVC so created an MVC site instead and worked with that.

Comment: @Moe Glad I could help (sorta) :P